# WinAPI - message loop with own callback

Tags: c++, c, winapi

The usual WinAPI message loop looks something like this:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0))
{
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Is it allowed not to call DispatchMessage() but to handle the message on your own? If not, how could I nicely approach this behavior while avoiding global variables and thread problems?

Edit:
I basically want to use my own callback function, which hasn't the WndProc signature. But I can't think of a way to call that function out of a WndProc without using static or global variables.
[Which would require locking, which I think isn't the best thing you can do with a callback function which probably gets called very frequently.]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `avoiding global variables and thread problems` Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @Jesse: I would expect he means the usual problems associated with using global variables that aren't const and are accessed by multiple threads.  Every thread using them has to use a locking mechanism to access them.

Comment: @Jesse edited. Hope it's better now.

Comment: You only need locking if you have multiple threads; the code above has one thread: each call to a WndProc owned by a given thread completes fully before the thread returns back to the loop and processes the next message, so you don't have to deal with concurrency issues here. Generally Win32 UI is written with a single thread for managing the UI with a single message loop, so you only have to deal with locking where you're using *additional* threads for background work.

Comment: Only a small spanner, but not everything goes through the message loop. `SendMessage()` from the same thread (at least) goes straight to `WndProc()`.

Answer (score 4):

> > Is it allowed not to call DispatchMessage() but to handle the message on your own? If not, how could I nicely approach this behavior while avoiding global variables and thread problems?

If you are planning to use multiple threads in your GUI then each thread that creates a window will need to manage it's own message queue.

From this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810439.aspx

> Changes to the Message Loop
>
> Applications with multiple threads must include a message loop in each
>   thread that creates a window. The message loop and window procedure
>   for a window must be processed by the thread that created the window.
>   If the message loop does not reside in the same thread that created
>   the window, the DispatchMessage function will not get messages for the
>   window. As a result, the window will appear but won't show activation
>   and won't repaint, be moved, receive mouse messages, or generally work
>   as you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can react to a message there, but you still need/want to call `DispatchMessage` and actually handle the message in your normal wndproc. I'd be happy to say more about avoiding globals and/or threading problems, but it's hard to comment without more details about what you want to avoid.

Comment: The function, in which the message loop is, calls another function, but that can happen from multiple threads / locations. Furthermore, I can't define this function as callback when creating the window class, since it doesn't has the right signature. I need a way to call this callbacks without having the DefWindowProc called. But the only way to communicate with a WndProc function seems to be over statics/globals.

Comment: 'he only way to communicate with a WndProc function seems to be over statics/globals' ??- - there are the two 32-bit 'wParam, lParam' parameters.  These could contain a pointer to your function and a struct pointer to as many parameters as you might want, or instances of any class you may wish.

Comment: @MartinJames: You are correct, of course, but to make your answer fully address his concerns you need to add this comment to it.

Comment: @MartinJames But when I change the wParam/lParam variables, the original message is lost? Ok, maybe I could make a struct which holds the original parameters and extra information and use a pointer to that. Is that the way you're thinking of?

Comment: @cooky451 - basically, yes, if needed.  I didn't know what you were using the params for, if anything, in your message so I didn't bother over-complicating my comment.

Comment: I don't understand please Jerry. I have an invisible message only window. I registered it to listen to raw input for mouse. I am getting the messages with the GetMessage loop but I am not doing DispatchMessage, is this bad? Should I dispatch message to my mssage windows wndproc? I can do that, but I dont use it there, justcurious should i do it or not please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can handle the message yourself, if you wish.  I usually set the result field to 0, but Windows only make use of this field for a few messages.

Comment: What do you mean with setting the result field to 0? What result field? - It seems there are two opinions here, so a little bit more explanation would be nice.

Comment: There is an int result field in the msg struct.